# How can I make jquery load after all images loaded completed?

Tags: jquery

I have a page full of images with different width and height. I need to get thire width. But jquery always make it before the images loaded. so the width of the image I got was a broken image width.

I tried $(document) and $(window), all faild. Anyone can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: document ready fires too early for my requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034810/jquery-document-ready-fires-too-early-for-my-requirements)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `$(window).load()` which will fire only when everything is fully loaded. The main drawback is that any interactivity code (such as button clicks) are available only after everything is loaded. A better alternative is to just defer the image handling code using something like the [imagesloaded plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) and use `$(document).ready()` for the rest of your code.