# jQuery loader for the intro

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Site have a small introduction with heavy images, here is the little animation on it:

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('#intro-left').stop().delay(5000).animate({'width':'0'},4000, 'easeOutQuint');
    $('#intro-right').stop().delay(5000).animate({'width':'0','left':'100%'},4000, 'easeOutQuint');
    $('#intro-rights').stop().delay(5000).animate({'width':'0','left':'100%'},4000, 'easeOutQuint');
    $('#intro-logo').stop().delay(10000).fadeOut(1500);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="intro-left"></div>
<div id="intro-right"></div>
<div id="intro-rights"></div>
<div id="intro-logo"><img class="top" src="images/intro_top.jpg"><img class="logo" src="images/intro-logo.jpg"><img class="bot" src="images/intro-bot.jpg"></div>
<div id="header">
    Rest of the Site...
```

CSS

```
#intro-left {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(images/intro-left.png) right no-repeat;
    width: 58%;
    height: 100%;
}  

#intro-right {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9000;
    top: 0;
    left: 32%;
    background: url(images/intro-right.png) left no-repeat;
    width: 68%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and as you can see, it is just full screen images and colors,  the problem is that the Web surfer may miss that intro, or, have it introduced in a bad way, with images loading... 
It make the intro ugly, then,
i want to know if there is a way to make all the content in the page invisible while it is loading, then, when all the content of that page is loaded, make it visible.
Maybe a display: none during the loading and then the page is loading make it block, something like that would work,

Is that posible? Or similar to it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following link will take you to a jquery loading plugin that allows you to add a pre-loader to your website which should be a great solution to your problem.

http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/

You would use the `onComplete()` function to have your intro start going after the page / pre-loader is finished.

Might look something like this:

```
 $("body").queryLoader2({
    barColor: "#6e6d73",
    backgroundColor: "#fff1b0",
    percentage: true,
    barHeight: 30,
    completeAnimation: "grow",
    onComplete: function(){
        $('#intro-left').stop().delay(5000).animate({'width':'0'},4000, 'easeOutQuint');
        $('#intro-right').stop().delay(5000).animate({'width':'0','left':'100%'},4000, 'easeOutQuint');
        $('#intro-rights').stop().delay(5000).animate({'width':'0','left':'100%'},4000, 'easeOutQuint');
        $('#intro-logo').stop().delay(10000).fadeOut(1500);
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is just on that, this preloader just create a 100% width and 100% height div over my site, then, when it is loaded, it fadeOut, but the problem is that the introduction is gonna be under that preloader div... Isnt there a way to make my jquery wait that div fadeOut? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use the plugin I mentioned, it provides a function called: `onComplete()` which allows you to start your intro after the animation and loading is finished.

Comment: Epic, just epic, but for use it is just add the jQuery function inside the onComplete's parentheses? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just added a sample of what the code might look like, you might have to fiddle around with it a bit though. 
Please accept this answer if it works for you so others with a similar problem will know the solution :)

Comment: THANKS A LOT GUY, IT WORKED JUST PERFECTLY!!! IT DID ALL I NEEDED TO. SORRY FOR TAKING SO LONG TO APROVE YOUR ANSWER. jUST EPIC!

Answer (score 1):

Try encasing the whole page contents in `<div id='loadHide' style='display:none'>...</div>`

You can then add

```
$('#loadHide').show();
```

To the beginning of your code block, to display the contents once the document has finished loading.

The finished javascript would be:

```
$(function(){
    $('#loadHide').show();
    $('#intro-left').stop().delay(5000).animate({'width':'0'},4000, 'easeOutQuint');
    $('#intro-right').stop().delay(5000).animate({'width':'0','left':'100%'},4000, 'easeOutQuint');
    $('#intro-rights').stop().delay(5000).animate({'width':'0','left':'100%'},4000, 'easeOutQuint');
    $('#intro-logo').stop().delay(10000).fadeOut(1500);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer me, but i tryed it and it is not working right, is just it? Put the whole body content into a div, put on that div an id, make it display:none and just add a $('#divId').show(); on the top of mine scripts? Thanks a lot again dude, but how about the loading gif?

Comment: I can't help much further unless you give better examples of the HTML you're using this code with, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks, already edited the question, now you can read some html in it. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

The display:none/display:block would likely work, and jQuery has a method of running code only after the page has fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').show();
    // I would also recommend that you start your animation here, too
});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(method)` is exactly the same as `$(method)`, which is already in use.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(document).ready` solutions are good, but the document can be ready before all of your images are finished loading. If your main concern is waiting until all images are loaded, I would check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034810/jquery-document-ready-fires-too-early-for-my-requirements), which suggests that you use the `$(window).load` callback. Also, you can add `onload` event handlers to your images to be sure you don't start animating before images are loaded.

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  //Animation code here
};
image.src = "http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/yW5Vv23HQWM/hqdefault.jpg";
```

This would only work if you are loading a single image. If you need to wait on more than one image, you would put your animation code somewhere else and each time an `onload` event was fired, you would check to see if all of your needed images are loaded yet. Once they have all loaded, call your animation code.